# Mixing HSV Channel

Tags: rendering, color, image, color-separation

[image: Composition of HSV]

I have a question about the saturation channel.
1.) So far I know, that saturation channel only give intensity to Hue channel, but I do not understand, how saturation channel can be dark and what is the saturation value to be in saturation channel dark?.

If I am not mistaken the range of value channel is from 0 to 100. 0 is black and 100 is white.
so I am trying to use [online HSV simulator](http://colorizer.org/) to figure it out what color can be produced after mixing each channel.

But I still searching the value for the black and white color in saturation channel so I can correct answer for each color on each box (a-d).

And how saturation channel can be dark if, the value channel has a value of 100 (based on onlie HSV simulator, H = 0-360, V = 100, S = ? )?

---

### sofar my answer is :

a. hell white without saturation.
b. dark gray with little saturation.
c. half gray.
d. dark black with low saturation.

is there any exact value for black and white in saturation channel?.

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer is a little off. When the saturation is 0, the hue is basically undefined. It has some numerical value, but that value is ignored. Saturation of 0 means achromatic, or uncolored. So it can only be a shade of gray.

Saturation is unrelated to value in HSV. You can have all of the following:

- dark unsaturated colors (basically dark grays or colors close to dark grays)
- dark saturated colors (think of a deep red wine color, for example)
- bright unsaturated colors (bright grays, pastels have a a little bit of saturation)
- bright saturated colors (like the red of a stop sign)

Looking at your example, it looks like the S channel has only 2 values: 0 and 100%.

Comment: so all of produced color after combining each channel will be only dark, gray and white right?
the different only about the saturation.

Comment: No, they won't all be dark, gray, and white. Only the ones where the saturation is 0 (black) will they be shades of gray. The other pixels where the saturation is not zero will have color.

Comment: I am still confused so based on the image that I gave, black on the saturation channel has the value of 0 is black and the value of 100 is white?
and if the saturation on that image is white they will have color, because the saturation is 100%?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Any saturation greater than 0 will have some color.

Comment: so just want to confirm. that in my example the box B and D must be have colors.
After reading your answer, I assume that, the box B has dark red saturated color and I think that, the box D does not make any sense, because the value is 100% and saturation can not be dark.
Correct me please if I am wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks to me like those 2 boxes both have 0 in the saturation channel, so no, I wouldn't expect them to have colors.

Comment: so which box has saturation if B and D does not have saturation?.
because the other boxes has zero saturation too  due to white color in the saturation channel.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your diagram? I'm taking the key to mean that black = 0 and white = 1 (or 0% and 100% if you prefer). So I'm reading it as cells A and C have 100% saturation and cells B and D have 0% saturation. If I have it backwards and white = 0% and black = 100%, then your earlier answer was correct.